# How to merge date and time column for backtesting purpose in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python to backtest on Nifty intraday data for past 9 years. For that I need accurate date and time column so that I can generate my Buy & Sell signal and backtest them.

This data gives me Date & Time in different columns, I want to merge both columns and I want to generate a time stamp like DD/MM/YYY HH:MM:SS

I have the following code as input.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('ticks2.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])

print(df.head())
type(df)
df.dtypes
```

Output

```
 Symbol       Date      Time     Open     High      Low    Close
0  NIFTY 2008-01-01  09:55:00  6138.60  6154.60  6138.60  6148.90
1  NIFTY 2008-01-01  09:56:00  6149.75  6149.75  6132.80  6132.80
2  NIFTY 2008-01-01  09:57:00  6138.25  6138.25  6127.95  6127.95
3  NIFTY 2008-01-01  09:58:00  6127.15  6127.15  6120.90  6120.90
4  NIFTY 2008-01-01  09:59:00  6118.05  6118.05  6113.55  6113.90
Out[28]:
Symbol            object
Date      datetime64[ns]
Time              object
Open             float64
High             float64
Low              float64
Close            float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the pandas documentation you can combine these when creating the dataframe you can use the parse dates on both columns like below.

```
df = pd.read_csv('ticks2.csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
```

More information on read_csv available in the documentation. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html